# Creating Collapsable Application Form

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I would like to create html application form page where on top there will a dropdown menu. Depending on the value chosen from that dropdown the area below dropdown menu will expand and have some input text boxes with labels. Since I am new to web development, I would be super glad to use simple to understand form.
Could you please share template or your solution to achieve this feature?
I don't ha`enter code here`

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <select name="occupation">
    <option value="student">Student</option>
    <option value="academician">Academician</option>    
  </select>
</form>
```

How to proceed from there? Any suggestion or advices, links would mean a lot.

Comment: This can't be achieved without CSS and JS

Comment: Please provide some code that you have already tried.

Comment: @Quentin ok I edited the question, thanks

Comment: @ZacWebb I added some, really have no idea how to proceed from there, deadline is pressing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without JS and CSS it is not possible, you have to use any client side script to make your DOM element interactive, I'm adding a sample code here:

You can further customize it by using some animation and using jQuery to make it more easier to you.

```js
var selEle = document.getElementById("formSelector");
selEle.onchange = function(){
    var selectedVal = selEle.options[selEle.selectedIndex].value;
    var allSections = document.getElementsByClassName("form-section");          
    for(var i = 0; i < allSections.length; i++){
      var ele = allSections.item(i);
      if(ele.id == selectedVal){
        ele.style.display = "block";
      }
      else{
         ele.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
}
```

```html
<form>
<label for="sectionSelector">Select Form Section</label>
<select id="formSelector" name="sectionSelector" onchange="runActFun(this)">
<option value="">-Select-</option>
<option value="section1">show Section Form 1</option>
<option value="section2">show Section Form 2</option>
</select>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="section1" class="form-section" style="display:none;">
<label for="input1_1">Input 1.2</label>
<input type="text" name="input1_1"></input>
<br/>
<br/>
<label for="input1_2">Input 1.2</label>
<input type="text" name="input1_2"></input>
</div>
<div id="section2" class="form-section" style="display:none;">
<label for="input2_1">Input 2.1</label>
<input type="text" name="input2_1"></input>
<br/>
<br/>
<label for="input2_2">Input 2.2</label>
<input type="text" name="input2_2"></input>
</div>

</label>

</form>
```

Comment: accept this answer and let other knows the solution